# createBitmap which resource size is used?

Tags: android, bitmap

I create a Bitmap from a vertical section of my picture. But i only want to show 20% of the picture and have it in many sizes in the resource folder. when i use static pixels the result is false.

```
Bitmap SOURCE_BITMAP = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bg_main);
int START_Y = 15;
int HEIGHT_PX = 500;

// Crop bitmap
Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(SOURCE_BITMAP, 0, START_Y, SOURCE_BITMAP.getWidth(), HEIGHT_PX, null, false);

// Assign new bitmap to ImageView
ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_bg);
image.setImageBitmap(newBitmap);
```

my idea was to assign `HEIGHT_PX` with `(int)(SOURCE_BITMAP.getHeight() * 0.2f);` but isn't there a better way to create the Bitmap without declaration of pixels (=relative to the size)?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use the already loaded Bitmap to find out how much 20% is since the size of the Bitmap already contains the density information (on a xhdpi screen the same image would have twice as many pixels as on a mdpi screen)
2. Or you can use the display density to convert an absolute pixel value to a value that considers the logical density of the screen. The absolute pixel value would be in relation to the mdpi bitmap on a 160dpi screen.

To get 20% of a Bitmap starting from pixel 15 you would do:

```
// retrieve screen density
Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
display.getMetrics( metrics );
float density = metrics.density;

// read Bitmap from resources
Bitmap source = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bg_main);
int y = Math.round(15f * density);
int height = Math.round(source.getHeight() * 0.2f);

// Crop bitmap
Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, y, source.getWidth(), height);
```